# LinkedIn inShare Plugin Sharing Counter returning Zeros

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I have a wordpress blog (http://bloculus.com/) where I use Super Socializer plugin to share my posts. Recently, I discovered that I lost all my LinkedIn share counts (in every post, it went back to 0).

I got in touch with the plugin author and we saw that the issue wasn't in his side.
When using the linkedin api, I see that I don't have any share on any post.

Here is an example:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://bloculus.com/process-communication-les-fondamentaux/&format=json
```

Response is:

```
{
"count": 0,
"fCnt": "0",
"fCntPlusOne": "1",
"url": "http://bloculus.com/process-communication-les-fondamentaux/"
}
```

Whereas I had a few hundreds of shares last week.

So my questions are:

- Given that I didn't change any of my posts URL, nor website settings (no change in http or https protocol), how is it possible to "loose" sharing count ?
- Is it a way to get all my counts back ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Apologies! We were running a test to determine the effectiveness of the share count number on the inShare button. The share count should be back for all users.

Comment: @StephenLynch The problem appears to be back today. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2018/deprecating-the-inshare-counter

The API was end-of-lifed, so results will return what you are seeing. I don't know of an existing workaround.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Makes sense. The blog post is largely content-free. It's just evidence of what I stated. But point taken. Thanks