# LinkedIn share count API with inShare is returning zeros

Tags: linkedin-api

We use the endpoint http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url= to measure the LinkedIn share count for selected URLs.

Since Thursday this has returned all zeros. I believe this may be related to the Deprecation of the inShare counter (https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2018/deprecating-the-inshare-counter).

On a previous question, Stephen Lynch mentioned that this was a test. Can you please confirm if this API has been fully deprecated? [LinkedIn sharing counts lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261160/linkedin-sharing-counts-lost)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedIn share count API (/countserv/count/share) always returns "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282250/linkedin-share-count-api-countserv-count-share-always-returns-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinkedIn sharing counts lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261160/linkedin-sharing-counts-lost)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's officially gone: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2018/deprecating-the-inshare-counter

The API has been deprecated. Searching for a workaround.

Comment: long story short, no.